# Not getting the right answer when dividing

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, code

```
echo off
title Numbers Part 3
color a
goto input
:input
echo what to divide?
set /p by=
cls
echo %by%?
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo Well, %by% by what?
set /p with=
pause
cls
echo Great
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
cls
goto answer
:answer
echo The Answer of %by% by %with% is
set /a Anser=%by%/%with%
echo %Anser%
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
echo code made by ******
pause
```

In this code, I am not able to get the correct answer
the decimals are not correct!
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

#### I am not able to get the correct answer the decimals are not correct!

> Any `SET /A` calculation that returns a fractional result will be rounded down to the nearest whole integer.

Source: [Set - Environment Variable - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

---

> How can I fix that?

You can't.

> There are no real workarounds that allow floating point math, except
> using other scripting languages.
>
> The only exception may be if you have
> a limited and fixed number of decimals (e.g. 2), then you can just
> multiply everything by 100.
>
> To display a decimal delimiter in the end
> results, concatenate the ineger divide by 100, followed by the decimal
> delimiter, followed by the modulo divide by 100:
>
> ```
> SET /A Whole = %Result% / 100
> SET /A "Fraction = %Result% %% 100"
> SET Result=%Whole%.%Fraction%
> ```
>
> This may break on the 32-bit limit, though.
>
> In general, for floating point math I would recommend using other
> scripting languages.

Source: [Batch files - Math](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php)